# rewrite rule problem?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have this problem with my url rewrite condition in .htaccess file, everything is working fine, but when i just type `www.example.com` on the browser to go to my homepage' it thinks its viewtopic.php file:

my viewtopic files are rewritten to be like this:

```
www.example.com/topic
```

this is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /viewprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !=viewtopic.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

how could i change that so it works normally?:)) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

Comment: where shall i put this at the end